# Superimposing plot over errorbars in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to superimpose a plot over my error bars. I have searched online and this seems to be the method to do this. I am expecting the plot to look the way it does however with thin black lines running between the thick colour lines.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10), dpi=80)
plt.grid(True, linewidth=0.5, color='#ff0000', linestyle='-')

for i in range(len(B_arrays)):
    plt.errorbar(T_arrays[i], B_arrays[i], STD_arrays[i], linestyle='None', marker='^', label = labels[i])
    plt.plot(T_arrays[i], B_arrays[i], color = "k")
    
plt.ylabel("B")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.legend(loc="upper right", prop={'size': 8})
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `plt.plot` for the black lines, but just adjust the [`zorder`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html):

- Either pull the black lines above with [`zorder`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html) > 2

  ```
  for t, b, std, label in zip(T_arrays, B_arrays, STD_arrays, labels):
      plt.errorbar(t, b, std, linestyle='None', marker='^', label=label)
      plt.plot(t, b, color='k', zorder=3)
      #                         ^^^^^^^^
  ```
- Or push the error bars below with [`zorder`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html) < 2

  ```
  for t, b, std, label in zip(T_arrays, B_arrays, STD_arrays, labels):
      plt.errorbar(t, b, std, linestyle='None', marker='^', label=label, zorder=1)
      plt.plot(t, b, color='k')
      #                                                                  ^^^^^^^^
  ```

The key value here is 2 because all lines (including error bars) have a default [`zorder`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html) of 2:

| Type | Default `zorder` |
| --- | --- |
| Images | 0 |
| Patches | 1 |
| Lines | 2 |
| Major ticks | 2.01 |
| Text | 3 |
| Legend | 5 |

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, however it is not the cleanest way. I'm open to better ways to do this if the community has other approaches.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10), dpi=80)
plt.grid(True, linewidth=0.5, color='#ff0000', linestyle='-')

for i in range(len(B_arrays)):
    plt.errorbar(T_arrays[i], B_arrays[i], STD_arrays[i], linestyle='None', marker='^', label = labels[i])
    plt.errorbar(T_arrays[i], B_arrays[i], np.zeros(len(B_arrays[i])),color = "k")
    
plt.ylabel("B")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.legend(loc="upper right", prop={'size': 8})
plt.show()
```

[image]